# Home automation

Tags: feature-request

Since home automation closed is it considered in-scope to ask Home Automation questions here and all questions that were asked (answered and not) in Home Automation to be transfered here? (ok questions like on I personally asked what should I use to build a home server in order to be ultra cheap and ultra low in sound do not have a place here but other questions on how to create set thing or how to monitor set thing I believe fit in the scope)

Comment: Most of the home automation type questions that have been asked here in the past, tend to be shopping type questions. I say in general from what I've seen so far, home automation is off topic.

Comment: Yes but what isn't Home automation part of improvement? (btw by shopping you mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industrial_arts right?)
where can we find the defined scope of Home improvement?

Comment: By shopping I mean "*[shop for me](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/q/607/33)*" type questions.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why was the home automation site closed?

Comment: Not so many questions asked during the beta phase. It's tough scope where few people know what to ask. I was never into home automation until I saw the site and afterwards with the help there I started automating my home. But it's not a subject that has many experts as of the moment

Answer (score 4):

After stumbling upon the questions that [@Shog9 migrated to the site](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18667/10080), only one of them appear to be on topic here (at least in my opinion).

These questions are all asking for a device, or group of devices that can accomplish a task. The user lists all the features they're looking for, and the answerers are meant to supply links to products that meet these criteria. Which to me seem to be [shop for me](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/607/33) type questions.

- [What device can remotely close a water main?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/52852/what-device-can-remotely-close-a-water-main?)
- [Detecting cigar/cigarette smoke levels](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/52848/detecting-cigar-cigarette-smoke-levels)
- [Door lock and unlock based on authorized user proximity](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/52843/door-lock-and-unlock-based-on-authorized-user-proximity)
- [Reliable, inexpensive way to be notified of a water leak?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/52854/reliable-inexpensive-way-to-be-notified-of-a-water-leak)

Out of the group of questions, this is the only one that seems on topic.

- [Why is a neutral wire needed for most 'smart' light switches?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/52859/why-is-a-neutral-wire-needed-for-most-smart-light-switches)

If this is any indication of the types of questions you're talking about, I'd say they don't really fit in here.