# Please Reopen This: I'm looking for a solution, not a product recommendation

Tags: discussion

[How should I solve this problem with my shower?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/80165/can-i-buy-a-shower-fixture-that-will-let-me-tilt-the-shower-head-up)

Please reopen this.

I'm looking for a solution, not a product recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voting to **reopen** because I could take a picture of my wye diverted dual shower head configuration (one is standard, one is a wand), *type in nothing* and likely get an accept. It's a solution recommendation, not a specific product. I couldn't even tell you who made them. China prob.

Answer (score 0):

I'm declining to reopen this question myself. As [originally written](https://diy.stackexchange.com/revisions/80165/1) this question was looking for a product recommendation or shopping advice. Our policy regarding product recommendation is covered in [this meta discussion](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/607/2196).

Looking at this question, it appears to be edited to remove the shopping question, and answers added in the comments are referring to products which I believe you are finding useful. For me, this meets several criteria to leave the question closed that I've addressed in the other meta post. Mainly the best answer for you appears to be a product link and edits to the question were intended to work around the product recommendation policy rather than clarify your question.

Product recommendations have a lot of issues on a site like this, they invite answers that quickly get outdated, often with little content around the answer, and create a situation that attracts legitimate users to post answers that would get flagged as spam. Marking a post as spam has a significant impact on a users reputation on the site, if not a complete ban from ever participating here in the future. So I'd rather error on the side of avoiding questions that attract false positive spam flags, rather than reopening a question that has been rephrased to avoid appearing as a product recommendation request.

Comment: Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0):

I had already voted to reopen.  I find this in the gray area of being a shopping question and my rule on this site is if it is in the gray area then it goes.  Because we have a lot of questions discussing brands/quality/ability.  It is a shopping question to a point but it really isn't brand specific so I think it goes.