# Closure: 'Except pitcher filters, are there portable water filters without electricity that filter chemicals, metals, and pathogens?'

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Please advise why https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/99930/54670 and https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/99934/54670 were unilaterally closed, and how they can be made on-topic again?

I ask because I had read the following that all seek recommendations too: [What type of filters should I use for a 3 stage whole house water filter?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/59378/54670), [What kind of filter do I need for well water?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/67823/54670).

Answer (score 6):

I'm not the person that closed your questions, but:

1. This is a site for **do-it-yourself Home Improvement**. You asked for a **portable** water filter, not something that you would install as a permanent fixture in a house. The other questions that you linked to are about equipment that is installed in houses.
2. You already know all the specifications for the filter you're looking for. ["Shop for me"](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/607/can-we-discourage-shop-for-me-type-questions) questions like that are off-topic here. See also https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/ for more guidelines about shopping questions.
3. The second question (about the electrically-powered filter) doesn't stand on its own. All the specifications are in the (non-powered filter question); I expect this is why it was closed as "unclear what you're asking" instead of "product or service recommendations".
4. You asked these questions on [Travel](http://travel.stackexchange.com) hours before asking them here on Home Improvement:

   - https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79496/except-pitcher-jug-filters-are-there-portable-water-filters-that-filter-chemica
   - https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79498/except-pitcher-filters-are-there-portable-water-filters-needing-electricity-tha

   Direct cross-posting like that is discouraged because it splits information in the answers across sites, making it harder to find for someone searching for the same information.